# c++ program to calculate solve piecewise function (involving pointers)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Hi I am currently having a problem with my code. I am designing a program involving pointers where user is prompted to enter min value and f(x) will be calculated, the result will be stored in array.

There's a few error in my code but im not very sure on how to solve them.

I hope someone can help me with this thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void piecewise(double[], int);

int main() {
  double fx[10][2] = {0};
  double *ptr;
  string text1 = "For x = ", text2 = ", f(x) = ";

  int min;
  cout << "Enter min integer value for x: ";
  cin >> min;

  int piecewise(fx, min);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // ptr points to row i column 0
  {
    ptr = &fx[i];
    cout << text1 << ptr;
    cout << text2 << fx[i][1] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

void piecewise(double fx[][2], int min) {
  int x = min;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    fx[i][0] = x;
    if (x < 2)
      fx[i][1] = x * x;
    else if (x == 2)
      fx[i][1] = 6;
    else
      fx[i][1] = 10 - x;
    x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: _There's a few error in my code_ What kind of error? Compiler error? Please, copy/paste the error message into your question and remark the line of occurrence in your exposed code. Run time error? Please, provide expected and current output. In any case, please, [edit] your question to provide that info.

Comment: int piecewise(fx, min); you are defining function not you using your function. remove before piecewise function.Then  you have dobule* and you are assign double(*)[2] so change ptr = &fx[i] to ptr = fx[i][1];

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code given and information provided I tried to debug it as much as possible.

**Errors I encountered:**

**1.**  You have declared the function `void piecewise(double[], int);` as `void` but have returned `int` value in `int piecewise(fx, min);`

**2.** You needed to provide the size of column in the function `void piecewise(double[], int);` as I encountered the ***error: multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first***.

**3.** You needed to provide the pointer correctly `ptr = &fx[i][0];` instead of just `ptr = &fx[i];` and also dereference it correctly like `cout << text1 << *ptr;`.

**4.** You need to start your loop from `i=0` in function `void piecewise(double fx[][2], int min)` not from `i=1.`

**Modified Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void piecewise(double[][2], int);

int main() {
  double fx[10][2] = {0};
  double *ptr;
  
  string text1 = "For x = ", text2 = ", f(x) = ";

  int min;
  cout << "Enter min integer value for x: ";
  cin >> min;

  piecewise(fx, min);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // ptr points to row i column 0
  {
    ptr = &fx[i][0];
    cout << text1 << *ptr;
    cout << text2 << fx[i][1] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

void piecewise(double fx[][2], int min) {
  int x = min;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fx[i][0] = x;
    if (x < 2)
      fx[i][1] = x * x;
    else if (x == 2)
      fx[i][1] = 6;
    else
      fx[i][1] = 10 - x;
    x++;
  }
}
```

**Input:**

`Enter min integer value for x: 4`

**Output:**

```
For x = 4, f(x) = 6                                                                                                   
For x = 5, f(x) = 5                                                                                                   
For x = 6, f(x) = 4
For x = 7, f(x) = 3                                                                                                   
For x = 8, f(x) = 2                                                                                                   
For x = 9, f(x) = 1                                                                                                   
For x = 10, f(x) = 0   
For x = 11, f(x) = -1
For x = 12, f(x) = -2
For x = 13, f(x) = -3
```